# Controlling selenium through a Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I've created a swing application that will essentially use selenium to monitor field values displayed on a website and log their results to a file. The reason I'm using a swing GUI is to allow users to easily input the fields they wish to monitor by adding it to a JList.

Everything is working fine but when I click the button "Start Monitoring" (which creates a selenium thread and runs it), the selenium thread completely takes over and does not allow any interaction with the swing GUI.

I would like a button on the swing GUI "Stop Monitoring" to stop selenium, but this isn't possible since because I can't interact with the swing GUI while selenium is running.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i try to do something similar. could you give me a pointer how to integrate a selenium controlled firefox instance into a swing gui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selenium code is locking the EDT or the Event Dispatch Thread, Swing's main thread for user interaction and GUI painting.  The solution is to call the selenium code in a background thread such as by using a SwingWorker object.  You can read more on how to do this at the SwingWorker tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Once you get this fixed, you should be able to get your "stop monitoring" JButton to work.